# Decorator Pattern from Head First Book wrongfully used?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator, builder

Currently I am reading "Head First Design Patterns". As you may look on pages 24 and 25 of the PDF [here](http://wickedlysmart.com/headfirstdesignpatterns/HFDP_sampler_Chapter3.pdf), I have doubt in given example.

Why don't we make something like:

```
public abstract class Beverage {

String description = "Unknown Beverage";
Double cost;
ArrayList<Topping> toppings;  // allows duplicates


public void addTopping(Topping topping){
toppings.add(topping);
cost+=topping.getCost();
}
getter/setter of description
getter/setter of cost
}



Public class Topping{
 String description;
 double cost;

    getter/setter of description
    getter/setter of cost

}
```

Then answering questions on page 25:

- *Price changes for condiments will force us to alter existing code*

  no they won't we can manipulate cost of the topping by `setter`.
- *New condiments will force us to add new methods and alter the cost method in the superclass*

  no, the method is the same.
- *What if a customer wants a double mocha?*

  not a problem

Here we can also add Builder pattern.

Why should you use the decorator pattern in this scenario? Is my solution not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not make beverage agnostic to the topping. This is a matter of design choice in my opinion, but the decorator pattern will make sure that your classes never need know of each other. Also, you have a higher risk of implementation changes causing code changes. Later in the book (and it is an *excellent* book), you'll see that you'd like each class to have one job and know of as little other classes as possible.

I'd still go with the decorator, although in such a simplistic example it's hard to see the benefits.

Comment: The issues related to single responsibility can be easily resolved by writing something like a `class Order { Beverage bev; List<Topping> toppings; double cost; }`. That's if it even is an issue, since often ingredients in a recipe really do depend on each other.